# Aggregate query with avg on pymongo get nan

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have an issue with the Average function in pymongo aggregate query.

I have a structure like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5afd9c675e3a1f0e9b830510'),
  'actor_gender': 'NaN',
  'actor_id': 'NaN',
  'actor_last_name': 'Safary',
  'actor_name': 'Darsheel',
  'actor_role': 'NaN',
  'director_id': 'NaN',
  'director_last_name': 'Khan',
  'director_name': 'Aamir',
  'movie_genre': 'Drama',
  'movie_name': 'Taare Zameen Par',
  'movie_rank': 8.5,
  'movie_year': 2007}
```

When I compute this query:

```
coll.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":{"movie_genre":"Drama"},
                    "avg":{"$avg":"$movie_rank"}}}])
```

I got this `nan` on the average:

```
{'_id': {'movie_genre': 'Drama'}, 'avg': nan}
```

Comment: Are all the values for 'movie_rank' valid numbers?

Comment: Yes, there are no NaN on the movie_rank values..

Comment: based on sample input, problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb aggregation with nan values give NAN as output(https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-27472) 
You must be having some nan values in the movie_rank field.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, but i've tried between two movies that have both "movie_rank" field with NO NaN and i got always avg:nan, so weird..

Comment: I think the error is in query, you have done filtering in _id field. Have you tried using $match for filtering data. Somwthing like this 
       ([{$match:{'movie_genre:' Drama'}}, {"$group":{"_id":'$movie_genre' ,
                    "avg":{"$avg":"$movie_rank"}}}])